# PIC16F648A programming - some functions don't work

Tags: c, pic, microprocessors

I have problems with successful pic programming work.. As i'm new in pic programming i started with lighting up 8-segment display LED one by one. Everything went well except **RB4 output LED didn't light up** (its not broken because i checked it with 5v through resistor). I thought its a problem but not so major so i went on.  Next aim was to light up all segments of display right up after stratup with code:

```
#include <htc.h>
void main()
{
  TRISB=0X00;
  PORTB=0X00;
  TRISA = 1;
  while(1)
  {
  PORTB=0XFF;
  }
}
```

This wasn't successful - **only 2 segments light up in startup and then immediately disappeared** and then none of LED lighted up afterwards.

I went even further after that problem - i wanted to turn on output when switch is pressed (High Input) and another time it was unsuccessful. **RB7 LED was on all the time**. Switch pressing didn't do anything. Code :

```
#include <htc.h>
void main()
{
  TRISB=0X00;
  PORTB=0X00;
  TRISA = 1;
  while(1)
  {
      if (RA4 == 1)  //Even tried TRISA4 ==1  //RB0 Dont light up, RB7 do light up all the time
      {
          RB0 = 1;
      }
      else
      {
          RB7 = 1;
      }
  }
}
```

> Can somebody please tell why i have these problems? Any solutions?

Btw - fuses were : `WDT OFF, BODEN ON, MCLRE OFF, Code protect OFF, PWRTE OFF, LVP ON, CPD OFF`

 **Im using K150 PIC Programmer**

1 : [**PIC pins**](http://circuits.datasheetdir.com/19/PIC16F648A-pinout.jpg)
2 : [**Circuit**](http://failiem.lv/thumb_show.php?i=xcugstt&view)

Comment: Is there more of your code or is that it?  Where are all of the pin initializations and definitions?  Do you have the header file that defines all of them for your specific chip?  Which compiler did you use?

Comment: Check this [sample post](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22437/setting-a-pin-on-porta-in-the-pic18f452-high-compilation-of-code-failed), the site where you should ask a question like this.

Comment: @MagisterLudi Thats it of code. All pins are automatically signed because at the beginning MPLAB asks for chip model.  I used MPLAB X IDE with XC8 compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's going on with the first snippet. The second one fails because

```
TRISA = 1
```

sets only RA0 as input. The rest of A pins (including RA4) are still output. You need something like

```
TRISA = 0x10;
```

Comment: `TRISA = 1` Defines A port pins as input. [I/O Ports](http://www.mikroe.com/chapters/view/4/chapter-3-i-o-ports/)

Answer (score 0):

RB4 is influenced by LVP.  In the "CONFIG – CONFIGURATION WORD REGISTER":

> LVP: Low-Voltage Programming Enable bit
>
> > 1 = RB4/PGM pin has PGM function, low-voltage programming enabled
> >     0 = RB4/PGM is digital I/O, HV on MCLR must be used for programming

which I'm guessing is why RB4 did not light up.

Reading RA4, clearly you need to set TRISA4.  Though I think it's in that state at power-up.  RA4's full name is RA4/T0CKI/CMP2.  At power-up the T0CS bit of the OPTION register is '1', which is:

> T0CS: TMR0 Clock Source Select bit
>
> > 1 = Transition on RA4/T0CKI/CMP2 pin
> >     0 = Internal instruction cycle clock (CLKOUT)

so clearing that might help.

The comparator stuff seems to wake up with the CMCON register all zeros, which puts CM2=CM1=CM0=0, which is "reset".  It's not clear to me how that affects RA4.  But it might be worth setting the comparators "off", ie CM2=CM1=CM0=1.

As far as the other effects you are seeing are concerned, I dunno :-(  It would be interesting to see what the little fragments of code compile to.

Comment: Thanks for a replay but this still didn't fix anything. With CM2=CM1=CM0=0 RB0 and RB7 are on, but with CM2=CM1=CM0=1 only RB0 is on. LVP not changing anything. Im switching to arduino :)